ESP32-WROOM ADC Issue: Sudden Failure in One PCB
I'm encountering a peculiar issue with an ESP32-WROOM ADC on a custom-designed PCB. The ADC has suddenly stopped working on one board, while it functions fine on others. Our design incorporates a current transformer (CT) with a ratio of 1:2500 for current measurement. We've encountered a similar problem in a previous project. What could be causing this sudden failure, and how can we troubleshoot it effectively?Schematic Schematic Current measurement measurement 
Schematic Schematic Micro-controller controller 
his problem is reminiscent of a similar issue encountered in a previous project, prompting concerns about the root cause and potential solutions. Here's an overview of our setup:
ESP32-WROOM Configuration: The ESP32-WROOM is interfaced with the ADC for measuring currents using the CT.
CT Configuration: We're utilizing a CT with a ratio of 1:2500 to accurately measure current values.
Schematic Overview: The ADC is connected to the CT output for current measurement, with proper signal conditioning circuitry in place.
Despite thorough testing and validation during the design phase, we're puzzled by the sudden failure of the ADC in one specific PCB. We've verified that power and connections are intact, ruling out common issues such as power supply disruptions or loose connections.
Given these circumstances, I'm seeking insights into the potential causes of this isolated failure and effective troubleshooting steps to pinpoint and resolve the issue. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This sounds like an electronics problem and should therefore post at https://electronics.stackexchange.com as Stack Overflow is for software/programming related question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
